# The private key for "myName" is not installed on this mac

Tags: ios, xcode

I get this message when trying to upload my app to the app store:

[image]

I've been hearing it is an issue in keychain, but this is what my keychain looks like:

[image]

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This had happened to me to. My problem was fixed by removing the duplicate keys.

Comment: Thnx, but if you look a pic 1, I believe there are no duplicates. Is it that there names are the same? They look different when I'm in the certificate tab. @siddharth

Comment: Well, I am looking at pic 1, there are two of them.

Comment: Should I name them Anthony Salah1 and Anthony Salah2?

Comment: Or should I just delete two of them? I believe one is for my developer certificate, and one is for my distribution certificate. Wouldn't it break the developer certificate is a delete those two keys? @siddharth

Comment: How I did it for, I deleted all of the them with same name, and then acquired a fresh new key.

Comment: Ok, and what is the process of getting a new key? Do I just apply for another certificate? Sorry, I'm really new to this. @siddharth

Comment: This one I am not sure about, cause I was working with a jailbreak key, but I'm sure there's an option for that.. Or if there isn't, you can just mail Apple